# How to add bootstrap img-fluid class to images using django-quill-editor

Tags: python-3.x, django, bootstrap-4

I am working on a blog project with Django using the django-quill-editor. Like the documentation says, I have imported QuillField and added it to my model as shown below. I have also added it to my admin.

Now the problem is that whenever i insert an image into the content field of the editor, The image is displayed fully on the details page of the blog. The image is not contained in any div, making it look out of proportion. I realize this is happening because the bootstrap class 'img-fluid' is not applied to the image. I want the image to fit into the text area. So I want know how to customize django quill editor to do this. I can't seem to find it in any documentation for django.

models.py

```
from django_quill.fields import QuillField

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    content = QuillField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to='banners/', blank=True, null=True, default='/banners/blog-1.jpg')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Comment

# Register your models here.

@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'publish', 'status')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'publish', 'author')
    search_fields = ('title', 'body')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    date_hierarchy = 'publish'
    ordering = ('status', 'publish')
```

Comment: In my case I can't even show the image in the detail page or any other page. If I add any image by clicking on the image icon in quill editor it does not get saved in the database.
what I figured out about the content field is, it is a text field. so would you please tell me how can I save image in database.

In my model I only have: content = QuillField()